# How to change color of a row in a wpf listview when using ItemSource and list view is added/removed dynamically c#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, itemsource

I have a WPF app that dynamically adds and removes tabs with list views as the content. I want to change the background color of a row in the list view based on the content of one of the columns in the row.

All of the solutions I have seen require using styles in XAML, which is incompatible with my current setup since the list views are created entirely in C# at runtime.

I have tried creating styles and adding data triggers and setters, but it doesn't seem to change anything. There are also multiple list views that should have different styles, so I'm not sure that changing the default style of all list views would be appropriate.

[image]

The content of the list view looks like this, and the WAR messages should have a yellow background:

[image]

Comment: The style with the WAR-yellow trigger needs to be applied to the `ItemContainerStyle` of the listview or a DataTemplate set as the 2nd columns `ListViewColumn.CellTemplate`. Applying the style and trigger , to the listview itself doesn't help because the property `Severity` doesn't resolve on the listview's DataContext (only on an item).

Comment: please add the code as text instead of linking an image

Comment: See: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1):

Per the comment from @lidqy, the solution to this was to change

```
logListView.Style = style;
```

to

```
logListView.ItemContainerStyle = style;
```

The Style declaration line also needed to be changed from

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ListView));
```

to

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.ListViewItem));
```

since ItemContainerStyle is apparently a style applied to ListViewItem (not ListView).